Oracle Linux 9.4 Display Issue
I have Two server running oracle linux 9.4
1st one is working good if i connect display.
2nd one have flicker issue or Display is totally black even though i upgrade the firmware, app update ,drivers but still no display. but if i restart i will get display for the 1st login time then  the next time if i try to login it will be totally black but
still i can access using remote.
kindly suggest me what can be done to rectify.
